# Django No password set in the admin Panel

Tags: django, authentication, passwords, set, admin

I have my own RegisterForm. I register successfully, and I can see a newly created user with its encrypted password in DBBrowser. But there's no encrypted password in the admin panel. When I look at the password field in the admin panel I only see "No Password Set" and more I can't log in with my newly created user's username and password. Thank you for your help.

My Code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            newUser = User(username= username, email = email)
            newUser.set_password(password)
            newUser.save()
            messages.success(request,"Kayıt İşlemi Başarılı.")
            login(request,newUser)
            return redirect("index")

        context = { 
                    "form" : form,
        }

        return render(request,"register.html", context)
    else:
        form = RegisterForm() #şimdilik içi boş. Sonra GET POST yapılacak
        context = { 
                    "form" : form,
        }

        return render(request,"register.html", context)
def loginUser(request):

    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form":form}

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")


        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password = password)

        if user is not None:

            messages.success(request,"Giriş Başarılı Şekilde Yapıldı.")
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("index")

        else:
            messages.info(request,"Kullanıcı Adı ya da Parola Hatalı.")
            return render(request,"login.html",context)

    return render(request,"login.html", context)


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "Çıkış Başarıyla Yapıldı.")
    return redirect("index")
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=20, label="Kullanıcı Adı")
    email = forms.EmailField(min_length = 4, label = "E-mail Adresi")
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=8, max_length=16, label = "Şifre", widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm = forms.CharField(min_length=8, max_length=16, label = "Şifre Doğrula", widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):

        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm")

        if password and confirm and password != confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Parolalar Eşleşmedi.")


        values = { 
            "username" : username,
            "password " : password,
            "email" : email}

        return values


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Kullanıcı Adı")
    password = forms.CharField(label= "Parola", widget= forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: In form's `clean` method you have `"password " : password,`. Try to remove space  after password: `"password" : password,`.

Comment: Ahaa.It's true. Thank you so much. I am very careless.